# How to add up the integers in a string? Java

Tags: java, numeric

I have been searching for a way to add the integers in a string and have found a few different responses saying to use:

```
String line = "123456789";
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0;i<line.length();i++) {
    total += Character.getNumericValue(line.charAt(i));
}
```

Is there a shorter way of doing this so that instead of looping through the String it will just add up each characters numeric value?

Comment: What do you mean by _it will just_?

Comment: there is always a shorter way to write code, but you should really step back and ask yourself if the readability of your code will benefit from doing so

Comment: Option 1 is to use a loop to get the value from each character and add them up. Option 2 is `int total = 45`.

Comment: "it will just" so that it automatically adds up the value of each integer between 0-9.

Comment: What do you mean _automatically_?

Answer (score 5):

You can convert the string to an `IntStream` (which will give the ascii code pour each char) then convert the ascii codes to their corresponding numeric value using `Character::getNumericValue` :

```
"123".chars().map(Character::getNumericValue).sum()
```

As stated in the questions comments, this is shorter but not the best way to do it. In a real application, I would use the extended version for its readability.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you do not want to loop through the string. In this you have to use the loop but loop will be "shorter" in some cases i.e. if string looks like "000000023" then instead of running 9 times loop will run only 2 times.

```
String s = "123456789";
 int x = Integer.parseInt(s);
 int sum = 0,val;
 while(x>0)
 {
   val = x%10;
   sum = sum + val;
   x = x/10;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want you can try something like this:

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(line)
while (x > 0) {
   sum = sum + x % 10;
   x = x / 10;
 }
```

or like this with regex:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d"); //single digit
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
while (m.find()) {            
   sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(m.group()); // convert in int every digit
}
```